# What numerical methods with variable step size are effective for computing double/triple integrals?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-integration

The professor asked me to write a small computer program that takes double integrals of rapidly varying functions. He did not mention which functions should be integrated but he said that I must use a numerical with variable step size.

I hope someone can recommend me a method that will do the job. It would also be nice to have a link where this method is adequately described.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/ better suited for this type of question. But still, I guess what your teacher wants you to do is to code a function `integrate(f,a,b,c,d)` where f can be any function, and in this function a step could be compute depending on the variation of f, integrate would integrate f over [c,d], than all over [a,b]. For such methods, you can start on wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Methods_for_one-dimensional_integrals